# Regex, get string value between two characters

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to return string between two characters, @ and dot (.).

I tried to use regex but cannot find it working.

```
(@(.*?).)
```

Anybody?

Comment: What are those outer parentheses for? Are they your delimiters? That might be a problem.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple @ characters or multiple dots?

Comment: [unrelated] while on the subject of regexes, I'd like to remind people of this hilarious answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/#1732454

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your regular expression almost works, you just forgot to escape the period. Also, in PHP you need delimiters:

```
'/@(.*?)\./s'
```

The s is the [DOTALL modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Here's a complete example of how you could use it in PHP:

```
$s = 'foo@bar.baz';
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/@(.*?)\./s', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that he was using multiline strings. Updated answer.

Comment: andreas didn't say he was working with strings with line breaks, I just mentioned that if he were, the proposed solution wouldn't work. And now it does, of course.

Comment: Ah, yes I see now. I'm wondering if he is trying to parse emails... just a guess though.

Comment: I try to get email address domain. @Mark Byers, your example shoots me with "Unknown modifier @". When adding \ before @ got blank page. Damn, hate regex :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm to tired :( Thanks Mark, your answer does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: andreas, how will you know on which DOT to split? What if the address is `name@some.domain.com` or `name@some.domain.co.uk`?

Comment: Also @ is a valid character in the first part of the address as long as it is escaped or in quotes, e.g. "firstname@lastname"@example.com - see http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3696.html page 6. You should consider using a standards compliant email parser rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @MarkByers what is the /s used for? it is working with just an '/' as an ending delimiter.

Answer (score 11):

Try this regular expression:

```
@([^.]*)\.
```

The expression `[^.]*` will match any number of any character other than the dot. And the plain dot needs to be escaped as it’s a special character.

Answer (score 4):

this is the best and fast to use

```
function get_string_between ($str,$from,$to) {

    $string = substr($str, strpos($str, $from) + strlen($from));

    if (strstr ($string,$to,TRUE) != FALSE) {

        $string = strstr ($string,$to,TRUE);

    }

    return $string;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're learning regex, you may want to analyse those too:

```
@\K[^.]++(?=\.)

(?<=@)[^.]++(?=\.)
```

Both these regular expressions use possessive quantifiers (`++`). Use them whenever you can, to prevent needless backtracking. Also, by using lookaround constructions (or `\K`), we can match the part between the `@` and the `.` in `$matches[0]`.