# PHP: What is the correct pattern for this? (preg_match)

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex, get string value between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034687/regex-get-string-value-between-two-characters)

myemail@gmail.com

What is the pattern to get what's between '@' and '.' in this string?
In this case it would get 'gmail'.

Comment: Regex can't reliably parse an email. What if you had the email `abc@subdomain.host.com`. The regex you request would only match subdomain when you would likely be looking for the host only (or the host and subdomain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is ...

```
preg_match("'@(.*?)\.'si", $source, $match);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$gmail = preg_match('/@([^\.]*)\./', $email, $m) ? $m[1] : false;
```