# PHP - Get random line from file with custom line ending

Tags: php

I am trying to save a random line from a file to a variable ($fortune), that part is easy. The part that I am having trouble with is the "line" can be multiple lines. Every line will end with \n% (enter key plus %). How would I get this to a variable? An example of the file is below:

> "There is a wiki on iptables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables and don't mess around with iptables - it's really tricky"
>
> Husse Mar 15 2007
>
> %
>
> "The Ubuntu developers have gone to great lengths
> to make sudo as smooth as possible in the GUI environment, and they've
> done a very good job. By re-enabling the root user and even logging in
> as root, you literally throw their work out the window, take your
> safety belt off and drive head-on into traffic. Yes, it is a bit
> insane.."
>
> Husse Mar 20 2007
>
> %

(It would pick everything before a "%")

Comment: `preg_split` maybe? Or `explode("\n%", $text);` or `"\n%\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$array = explode("\n%\n", $text);

print_r($array);
```

Or:

```
$array = array_map('trim', explode("%", $text));

print_r($array);
```

Where `$text` is the string that you read from the file.

Comment: This only works if there is no space or any sign between the lines themselves though.

Comment: And...  The OP can show what is in the file.  What they show appears to be `\n%\n`

Comment: you can use % sign to explode the sting and then use trim to remove the additional line spacing.

Comment: Based on what you said I got this:
`<?php 
$file = file("file.txt");
$text = $file[array_rand($file)];
 print_r(array_map('trim', explode("%", $text)); ?>`
But it does not work

Comment: I see.  When you just throw code together with no idea what it's doing it usually doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a regular expression to catch all of that?

Rather chunked, but here is what I got:

```
php > preg_match("/%(.*?)%/s", $str, $arr);
php > print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => %
my fortune is quite the ugly one

litterally
%
    [1] => 
my fortune is quite the ugly one

litterally

)
```

Its not the most optimal regualr expression, and I basically took my inspiration from here: [Regex, get string value between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034687/regex-get-string-value-between-two-characters)

But it should get you started!