# How do grab words that start and end with double percent signs?

Tags: php, regex

I am really bad at regex and I am trying to do the following:

How do I get all strings that starts and end with `%%`.

If these words appear in a string I want to be able to grab them: `%%HELLO_WOLD%%`, `%%STUFF%%`

Here's what I came up with so far: `%%[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+`

Comment: `%%.*%%` is all you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex, get string value between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034687/regex-get-string-value-between-two-characters) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud and many others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: What should be the result for these two strings `%%HELLO_WOLD%%%%STUFF%%` and `%%HELLO_WOLD%%STUFF%%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line and match zero or more times any character `.*` or if there must be at least one character your might use `.+`

[`^%%.*%%$`](https://regex101.com/r/erBQtG/1)

Or instead of `.*` you could add your character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which will match lower and uppercase characters and digits or use the  `\w+` which will match a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

**Note** that the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not match an underscore and `\w` does.

If you want to find multiple matches in a string you might use [`%%\w+%%`](https://regex101.com/r/Ne5lJ2/1). This will also match `%%HELLO_WOLD%%` in `%%%%%HELLO_WOLD%%%`.

If there should be only 2 percentage signs at the beginning and at the end, you could use a positive lookahead `(?=` and positive lookbehind `(?<=` to assert that what is before and after the 2 percentage signs is not a percentage sign or are the start `^` or end `$` of the string.

[`(?<=^|[^%])%%\w+%%(?=[^%]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cBHyn1/1)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will not match an underscore though

Comment: Using anchors seems ill-advised because the OP is trying to match multiple occurrences in a string.  Also, a greedy quantifier on `.` is going to be bad too.  If you are going to answer this mega-duplicate, you should probably do some repairs on this answer for the benefit of the OP and future researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your comment, I see your point according to the multiple occurrences and I have updated my answer. Can you elaborate on the `bad` part of using a greedy quantifier when using anchors?

Comment: No, you're good to go greedy with the anchors. Just that greedy is bad for multiple matches.

Comment: I wouldn't mention anchors or lookarounds at all because they are unnecessary.   But I'm not your boss and this is not my answer.